# Declaring type after it is parsed as a JSON file Swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode

Right now I have a JSON output that I got from Pearson's API:

```
Optional(<__NSCFArray 0x7f9b7601a910>(
{
    datasets =     (
        laad3,
        dictionary
    );
    headword = theoretically;
    id = cs1tNTvYvg;
    "part_of_speech" = adverb;
    senses =     (
                {
            definition = "used to say that something could happen, but it is extremely unlikely";
            examples =             (
                                {
                    text = "It\U2019s theoretically possible for everyone in the class to get 100%.";
                }
            );
        }
    );
    url = "/v2/dictionaries/entries/cs1tNTvYvg";
},
{
    datasets =     (
        laad3,
        dictionary
    );
    headword = theoretical;
    id = cs1tNTpDbZ;
    "part_of_speech" = adjective;
    senses =     (
                {
            definition = "relating to or based on ideas, especially scientific ideas, rather than practical work or experience";
            examples =             (
                                {
                    text = "theoretical research";
                }
            );
        }
    );
    url = "/v2/dictionaries/entries/cs1tNTpDbZ";
})
```

And assume that the output above is stored to:

```
let results = parsedResult!["results"]
```

XCode says that there is an ambiguous use of subscript and after Googling it seems that I have to cast the type of results to continue. What would I have to cast the type of `results` to e.g. `[[String:String]]`?

Side note: Does anyone know why Xcode complains that there is an ambiguous use of subscript when selecting the run target to be on my iPhone6 with iOS 9.3, but not while running in the simulator (also on iPhone6 with iOS9.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the deeper cause of this problem. But since XCode 7.3 (or rather with Swift 2.2), the compiler now complains about *ambiguous use of subscript* when using `NSDictionary`.

To avoid the error, cast `NSDictionary` instances to `[String: AnyObject]` and `NSArray` instances to `[AnyObject]`.